Overriding multiprocessing.queues.Queue put method
I want to implement a multiprocessing.Queue that does not add an element that already exists.
Using Python STL Queue I had no problem, following this response. For multiprocessing I had some issues that I solved thanks to this
For that I do the following:
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
from multiprocessing import get_context


class CustomQueue(Queue):
    def put(self, obj, block=True, timeout=None):
        if obj not in self:
            return super().put(obj, block, timeout)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        with self.mutex:
            return item in self.queue

custom_queue = CustomQueue(ctx=get_context())

However, when I call the put method I get AttributeError: 'CustomQueue' object has no attribute 'mutex'
How can I solve this issue?
Thank you in advance.

I read the code of multiprocessing.queues.Queue, and did my change to this:
class CustomQueue(Queue):
    def put(self, obj, block=True, timeout=None):
        if self._closed:
            raise ValueError(f"Queue {self!r} is closed")
        if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):
            raise Full

        with self._notempty:
            if self._thread is None:
                self._start_thread()
            if obj not in self._buffer:
                self._buffer.append(obj)
                self._notempty.notify()

But still does not work. self._buffer seems to be the queue (is a collections.deque object). But the obj not in self._buffer returns always True. Why is this happening?

Rather than assuming how a queue.Queue is implemented, which could change in the future, I would prefer the following. To keep track of what has been put on the queue but not yet gotten in such a way where no assumption of how the queue is implemented, we need a separate set or dict that gets updated every time a get or put call is made and this set must be shareable across processes. For this we can used a managed dictionary (which, unfortunately, will slow down get and put operations -- but no more than your implementation that is based on a managed queue):
from multiprocessing import Queue, Lock, Manager, Process

class CustomQueue:
    def __init__(self, syncmanager, maxsize=0):
        self._queue = Queue(maxsize)
        self._lock = Lock()
        self._items = syncmanager.dict()

    def put(self, obj, block=True, timeout=None):
        with self._lock:
            if obj not in self._items:
                self._items[obj] = None
                self._queue.put(obj, block=block, timeout=timeout)

    def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        obj = self._queue.get(block=block, timeout=timeout)
        # No exception raised so we retrieved an item:
        with self._lock:
            if obj in self._items:
                del self._items[obj]  # remove
        return obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Call all other methods of Queue."""
        if name == '__getstate__':
            return object.__getstate__

        if name == '__setstate__':
            return object.__setstate__

        return getattr(self._queue, name)

def putter1(q):
    q.put(1)
    q.put(2)

def putter2(q):
    q.put(1)
    q.put(3)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        q = CustomQueue(manager)

        p1 = Process(target=putter1, args=(q,))
        p1.start()

        p2 = Process(target=putter2, args=(q,))
        p2.start()

        # Give subprocesses a chance to put their items:
        import time
        time.sleep(1)

        for _ in range(3):
            print(q.get())

        p1.join()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
1
2
3

If you are not concerned about how a queue.Queue implementation might change in the future, I would still make changes to your implementation in which I see a race condition. Your __contains__ method checks to see if the item being put is already in the queue using a lock, but once it returns True or False back to the caller put, it has released the lock and there is a window in which another process might have already put a duplicate item on the queue prior to put putting the same item again. Therefore, the testing for the presence of the item on the queue and the actual placing of the item on the queue constitute a critical section and both operations must be done under control of a lock:
from queue import Queue
from threading import Lock
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import Process


class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass


class NoRepetitionQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
        super().__init__(maxsize)
        self._lock = Lock()

    def put(self, obj, block=True, timeout=None):
        with self._lock:
            if obj not in self.queue:
                return super().put(obj, block=block, timeout=timeout)


MyManager.register("NoRepetitionQueue", NoRepetitionQueue)

def putter1(q):
    q.put(1)
    q.put(2)

def putter2(q):
    q.put(1)
    q.put(3)

def main():
    with MyManager() as manager:
        q = manager.NoRepetitionQueue()

        p1 = Process(target=putter1, args=(q,))
        p1.start()

        p2 = Process(target=putter2, args=(q,))
        p2.start()

        # Give subprocesses a chance to put their items:
        import time
        time.sleep(1)

        for _ in range(3):
            print(q.get())

        p1.join()
        p2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Indeed, I want to add an item to the queue that has been previously added as long as that previously-added item has been "gotten". Your second solution is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Mhm, I have a problem that I can seem to solve, apparently the put method never returns, it get stuck. Did you try this using different processes?

I am sorry about that. The problem with my posted code is that the set used to track what is currently on the queue needs to be shareable across processes. I have updated the code accordingly and added a test that uses multiple processes.

One last questions, I understood using with self.mutex was the thread safety, so I though... A lock. This is wrong?

I think I answered my own question. mutex is for threading. But does not work on multiprocessing. That is why Lock should be used and mutex is not enough.

A mutex is just a nother name for a lock. In this case the attribute self.mutex  (that is, an attribute of a queue.Queue instance) is an instance of threading.Lock, which is used for multithreading. A lock that is to be used with multiple processes would be a multiprocesing.Lock. For managed objects you only need a threading.Lock since all method calls are executed within a single process created by a multiprocessing.BaseManager or its subclass.

Ok, in the end I created a STD queue and used SyncManager like this:
from queue import Queue
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager


class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass


class NoRepetitionQueue(Queue):
    def put(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        if obj not in self:
            return super().put(obj, *args, **kwargs)

    def __contains__(self, obj):
        with self.mutex:
            return obj in self.queue


MyManager.register("NoRepetitionQueue", NoRepetitionQueue)


def Manager():
    m = MyManager()
    m.start()
    return m


m = Manager()


def get_queue():
    return m.NoRepetitionQueue()


